# Regular Expression not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

This is **working fine** if i am writing jpg|png|jpeg|gif here...

```
if (!(ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))) {
                            alert('Error: extension is not allowed!' + Extensions + ' file ext: ' + ext);
                            return false;
                        }
```

If i use **variable** instead of static then **it is not working**

```
var Extensions = "jpg|png|jpeg|gif";
if (!(ext && /^(Extensions)$/.test(ext))) {
                            alert('Error: extension is not allowed!' + Extensions + ' file ext: ' + ext);
                            return false;
                        }
```

Thanks in advance
Imdadhusen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
(new RegExp("jpg|png|jpeg|gif")).test(ext)
```

Comment: You can do it that way as long as the string you use is a valid regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You are using invalid syntax for the regular expression. If you are going to store it in a variable, you must still use your regular expression from your first example.

So:

```
var Extensions = /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/;
if (!(ext && Extensions.test(ext)))
```

will work. Your second example is trying to match the word 'Extensions'.

Comment: but my requirement is **i have also dynamic value of variable**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Extensions = /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/;
if (!(ext && Extensions.test(ext))) {
    alert('Error: extension is not allowed!' + Extensions + ' file ext: ' + ext);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to omit the quotes, e.g. `var Extensions = /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/;`

Comment: but my requirement is **i have also dynamic value of variable**

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable, you need to use the RegExp object:

```
new RegExp('^(' + Extensions + ')$').test(ext)
```

Or assign the entire regex into your variable:

```
var Extensions = /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/; 
Extensions.test(ext)
```

Perhaps call it allowedExtensions or something though.

Answer (score 0):

it wont get error

```
var Extensions = "/^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/";
    if (!(ext && Extensions.test(ext))) {
                                alert('Error: extension is not allowed!' + Extensions + ' file ext: ' + ext);
                                return false;
                            }
```

Comment: Your answer is the same as megaperlz.